# Ширина в спойлере

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте, у меня стоит несколько блоков в строчку и когда я открываю сполер строчки сдвигаются, т.к. не хватает места в спойлере. Мне надо сделать чтоб когда спойлер открывался и в нутри спойлера была определенная ширина (80px;)

Вот скрипт js:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
         var spoiler_links = $(".spoiler_links");

         spoiler_links.parent().css('display', 'inline-block');
         spoiler_links.click(function(){
             $(this).parent().children('div.spoiler_body').toggle('normal');
             return false;
         });
    });
</script>
```

css:

```
.spoiler_body {
    display: none;
}
```

Спойлер:

```
 <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="spoiler_links">Текст, при нажатии которого открывается спойлер</a>
        <div class="spoiler_body">
           внутри спойлера как раз здесь мне и надо сделать, чтоб больше 80px; он не распространялся      
          </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тогда лучше использовать .slideToggle() вместо .toggle(). Так ширина меняться не будет.

Comment: Надо ее зафиксировать и сделать overflow:hidden, чтобы широкие элементы обрезались.

Comment: А как фиксировать?

Comment: Очевидно же:
width:80px;

Comment: ) щас попробую 

`
.spoiler_body {
    display: none;
    overflow:hidden
    width:80px;
}
`
Так?

Comment: Не хватает ; после hidden

Comment: Почти нормально, но нету переноса строк. Т.е. просто идет в одну строчку, а что не входит в эти пиксели, то просто не отображает.

Comment: Значит прописано white-space: nowrap; Надо сделать white-space: normal;